# Display set of user chosen categories on magento home page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am trying to display categories on magento home page. I know how to do it in a normal way using magento collections. I want to have it like a widget, if you insert a category link widget in static block or cms page, you can see the following:

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/3"}}
```

Now, here the `id_path` indicates which category to display. Can we modify it somehow to show a list of specified categories. For example like this: `id_path = '3,4,5,6'` so it will display all these specified categories. Can anybody guide me a way to do this? I don't know much about widget coding stuff in magento.

Comment: Well you can add as many as widgets inside the static block by selecting the widget as many as times you want.

Comment: yes..you are right..but I want to show category name along with its image..any suggestions??

Comment: Can you post a new question since this out of scope of what you have asked earlier and somebody may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many as widgets inside the static block by selecting the widget as many as times you want.

Comment: what you are saying I already know that..I want to do it as in my example in question..I want to modify it..image comes later..